# How do I prevent Windows from stopping my task (created in Task Scheduler) when switching to battery power?

Tags: windows-10, task-scheduler

I have two tasks created, which otherwise run perfectly. The problem occurs only if I switch to battery power, as indicated by history of task run.

How do I keep these tasks from being stopped by Windows?

Comment: It isn't clear whether you're asking how to disable the tasks, or how to disable Windows' ability to stop the tasks.

Comment: I want to stop Windows from stopping my tasks.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is caused by a setting that is greyed out and yet still active. To resolve, edit the task and proceed as follows:

1. Go to Conditions tab.
2. Check the box "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power" (even if that's not what you want).
3. The checkbox "Stop if the computer switches to battery power" will now be enabled and it's probably checked. Uncheck it.
4. Uncheck the box "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power" (unless that's what you want).

You may wish to proceed similarly with the "Idle" settings above. In a similar way, the "Stop if the computer ceases to be idle" checkbox is selected but disabled.

This seems to have stopped Windows from killing tasks for me when I switch to batteries.

Comment: Thanks but already tried that.

Comment: Can you post any error or stop codes that appear in the history?

Comment: As I said, I am on build 1903 now and this problem has been resolved already.

Comment: Can't see where you said that, but glad it's sorted for you.

Comment: Somebody deleted that post asking for additional information. Don't know if you can see it or not. But here you go, https://superuser.com/a/1484611/906385

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "Conditions" tab.
2. Check the box "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power" (even if that's not what you want).
3. The checkbox "Stop if the computer switches to battery power" will now be enabled and it's probably checked. Uncheck it.
4. Uncheck the box "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power" (unless that's what you want).
5. After this, you must turn off the battery saver (if you are using the battery saver) to run the task automatically.